# mvc4 + Compiler Error Message: CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble with my contact form.  It says:  Compiler Error Message: CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.  I tried to use the @using ... statement without luck.  I also used the @models with both capital and lower case "m" and no luck.  Please explain with great detail the solution(s).  I'm using Visual Studio 2012, if it helps.

Here is the code;
html:

```
@Model img_site.Models.customer;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
    <link href="~/Content/css/cnt-us_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    ViewBag.update = "May14, 2014"; } ... @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "HomeCotroller", FormMethod.Post , new { @name = "cnt_us-frm" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="Fname"> First name  <span class="important"> * </span> </label> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Fname, new { @tabindex="0"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Fname)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <label for="Lname"> Last name </label> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Lname, new { @tabindex="1"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Lname)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="te;_area"> Telephone <span class="important"> * </span> </label> 
                </td>
                <td>(@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.tel_area, new {@size="1", @maxlength="3", @tabindex="2"}))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.tel_area)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.fir_thr_tel, new {@size="1", @maxlength="3", @tabindex="3"}) -
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.fir_thr_tel)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.lst_fur_tel, new {@size="2", @maxlength="4", @tabindex="4"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.lst_fur_tel)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="Email"> Email <span class="important"> * </span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Email , new { @tabindex="5"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Email)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>]
                <td>
                    <label for="Reasn"> Reason <span class="important"> * </span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Reasn, new { @tabindex="6"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Reasn)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="buttons">
                <td>
                    <input type="reset" id="resbnt" value="Reset" tabindex="7" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="subnt" value="Submit" tabindex="8" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset> }
```

model:

```
namespace img_site.Models
{
    public class customer
    {
        ...
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "first name is required!")]
        public string Fname { get; set; }

        public string Lname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "area code is required!")]
        [StringLength(3)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{3,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 numbers required & contain only numbers")]
        public string tel_area { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "first three numbers are required!")]
        [StringLength(3)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{3,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 numbers required & contain only numbers")]
        public string fir_thr_tel { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "last four numbers are required!")]
        [StringLength(4)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{4,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 4 numbers required & contain only numbers")]
        public string lst_fur_tel { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-mail is required!")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A reason is required!")]
        public string Reasn { get; set; }

        public string Tele { get; set; }

        public void Tele_comp()
        {
            Tele = "(" + tel_area + ")" + fir_thr_tel + "-" + lst_fur_tel;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the top of the view, it should be

```
@model img_site.Models.customer
```

not

```
@Model img_site.Models.customer;
```

then in your expressions, it should be

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fname, ...
```

not

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Fname, ...
```